# How to add caption and label in tabular while using strip environment?

Tags: captions, labels

I am using IEEE Access template to write the paper and in the middle of the page, I need to insert a table that spans across both columns. Therefore, I used **strip**. The output I am getting is shown in the image below. 
[image]

The problem is that I am unable to write the caption as per IEEE Access style which is shown in the image below.
[image]

Below is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}


\begin{abstract}
These instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for 
IEEE Access. Use this document as a template if you are 
using \LaTeX.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
A,B,C
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. 
\begin{strip}
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{45pt}|p{115pt}|p{150pt}|p{150pt}|}
\hline
\textbf{Reference} & \textbf{Technique(s)} & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Findings} \\
\hline
[1] & Text & Some Text & Some More Text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{strip}
\EOD

\end{document}
```

Kindly help how can I add caption and label in the prescribed format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `\captionof` command from the `capt-of` package. In your MWE,

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}

\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}


\begin{abstract}
These instructions give you guidelines for preparing papers for 
IEEE Access. Use this document as a template if you are 
using \LaTeX.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
A,B,C
\end{keywords}

\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} document is a template for \LaTeX. 
\begin{strip}
\centering
\captionof{table}{Text of the caption.}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|p{45pt}|p{115pt}|p{150pt}|p{150pt}|}
\hline
\textbf{Reference} & \textbf{Technique(s)} & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Findings} \\
\hline
[1] & Text & Some Text & Some More Text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{strip}
\EOD

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for. Cheers

Comment: The `\captionof` command is also defined by the `caption` package, if happen to load it already.